# Mockito "when" method does not match lambda argument on RestTemplateBuilder requestFactory in spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-2

I am having an issue when trying to mock restTemplateBuilder:

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();


    return restTemplateBuilder.
           requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client)).
           build();
}
```

My test method setup below:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(() -> any(ClientHttpRequestFactory.class))).thenReturn(restTemplateBuilder);
        when(restTemplateBuilder.build()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
    }
```

In this case, requestFactory always returns null.
Mockito also gives me a hint that first line in setup is not in use, and ask on the line with requestFactory if "args ok?".

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory ` instead of `ClientHttpRequestFactory ` in `any`?

Comment: It makes no difference here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a matcher for the lambda function in your when clause. You can use [argThat](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat(org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher)) from Mockito like:

```
when(restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(argThat(()-> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(clientMock))).thenReturn(restTemplateBuilder);
```

Having client as a mock.

---

Another way to do it could be using ArgumentCaptor:

```
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Supplier> lambdaCaptor;
```

and using it:

```
when(restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(lambdaCaptor.capture()).thenReturn(restTemplateBuilder);
```

If you need more info about matching lambdas check [the documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#36).

Comment: So the first option does not work for me, having error that "Cannot resolve method 'requestFactory(T)'". 
Second one works with 
@Captor private ArgumentCaptor<Supplier> lambdaCaptor;